# React - Problem with update state (useState) in onChange function

Tags: reactjs, use-state

### I'm having a problem updating the state on a handleItemChange function for a form. Do you have a solution ? thank you so much...

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

const addPrestation = () => {

    const id = Date.now().toString();
    const prestation = {...items};
    prestation[id] = {
        customer:customer,
        id: id,
        delivery: "",
        quantity: "",
        unit: "",
        unitPrice: "",
        tva: "",
        htAmount: "",
        ttcAmount: ""
    }
    setItems([...items, {prestation:prestation}])
}

 const handleItemChange = (event, prestation, field ) => {
   const value = event.target.value;
   const clonePresta = {...prestation};
   clonePresta[field] = value;
   const clonePrestations = {...items};
   clonePrestations[clonePresta.id] = clonePresta;

   setItems(???)
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const handlePrestaChange = ({currentTarget}) => {
    const {name, value, id} = currentTarget;
    const clonePresta = {...prestation}
    clonePresta[name] = value;
    setPrestation({...prestation, [name]: value })
    const tabItems = [...items];
    tabItems[id] = clonePresta;
    setItems([...tabItems])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like that:

```
const handleItemChange = (event, prestation, field ) => {
   const value = event.target.value;
   const clonePresta = {...prestation};
   clonePresta[field] = value;
   const clonePrestations = {...items};
   clonePrestations[clonePresta.id] = clonePresta;

   setItems([...items, {presentation: clonePresta})
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help but Unfortunately this action adds new fields to each entry with an identical id which causes an error

Comment: Please, make an example on https://codepen.com or https://jsfiddle.net so that I can help you.